# How to accurately simulate an anamorphic lens

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, depth-of-field

I am aware of the aperture ratio slider in the camera properties. However, I am wondering if there is a way to actually render squished in Blender, and stretch it out in the compositor later. I honestly don't fully understand anamorphic lenses, so I might be asking the wrong question.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23408/rendered-aspect-ratio-different-from-the-viewports-camera-view/23409#23409

Comment: related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamorphic_format

Comment: related: https://code.blender.org/2014/08/anamorphic-bokeh/

Comment: To simulate the ellipsoidal bokeh of anamorphic lenses: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74527/bokeh-from-horizontal-to-vertical/74533#74533

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to anamorphize the rendered image by controling the aspect ratio values

[image]

The values depend on the proportions of the container.

For a 1.33 image the anamorphic pixel ratio should be 2:1 meaning that the image should be squeezed 2 times horizontally (X axis)

The unsqueezed image would have a format of 2.35:1

For a 16X9 image the anamorphic pixel ratio should be 1.33

Answer (score 1):

i'm late to the party here but this will do what your looking for
https://www.blendermarket.com/products/jackimorphic-camera-pack-v1

This an optics sort of question, the aperture slider only stretches the shape of aperture to fake the effect to the bokeh,  such as ‘Anamorfake’ lens search on google will show the photography equivelent.  This addon listing is a blender file that provides precise geometry of t the actual optics of anamorphic lenses to achieve the characteristics you are looking for, especially the compression of depth.

Flares would happen with this method if a wavelength dependant coating could be simulated in a fast way that didnt require so many more bounced light paths

-jack

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/163376)

Comment: Sorry! Ill edit