# Camera resizing

Tags: animation, camera

I've got a problem with resizing the camera viewport. I wanted to resize one camera, but instead it resizes every camera I have in the scene. Is there a away to only resize one camera?

I have this camera settings.
[image: I have this]

But wanted this without changing the other camera settings.
[image]

Comment: The resolution settings are for the whole scene. Besides, DO NOT CHANGE ASPECT RATIO settings unless you are going to export to a format that uses anamorphic ( non-square pixels) pixels. To render an image with vertical aspect, change the resolution instead: Switch the numbers for X and Y resolution.  Please read:   http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23408/rendered-aspect-ratio-different-from-the-viewports-camera-view/23409#23409

Answer (score 1):

You can't resize only one camera because after all it's how it will be rendered. You can't render the animations with different resolutions changing.