# How to render in square proportion

Tags: rendering

I want to render in square proportion. When i go to setting and adjust it never set in square. Always go in rectangle direction. How can i set my camera in square so that it render fast in that area only. Any suggestion or help or what setting i can use to set in a square.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to ***Properties>>Render>>Dimensions>>Resolution***.  Make sure the X and Y are set to the same value.  Also make sure that the aspect ratio for both X and Y is set to 1:

[image]

As @cegaton mentioned: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23409/38953

Comment: The rule of thumb: Do not touch the Aspect Ratio settings unless you know that you need to render anamorphic pixels. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23408/rendered-aspect-ratio-different-from-the-viewports-camera-view/23409#23409