# Rectangular/Portrait orientation. Is there any way to change the size of the camera?

Tags: camera

I'm trying to make a rectangular/portrait orientation style image for the camera in Blender 2.8. I've tried adjusting the aspect ratio, but all it does is the stretch the image. Is there any way you can adjust the size of the camera?

How it is now.

[image: How I]

How I want it to be.

[image]

Comment: Don't touch the aspect ratio settings, those will change the shape of your pixels. Use the resolution instead. Unless you are dealing with anamorphic images you should never have to use the aspect ratio settings. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23408/rendered-aspect-ratio-different-from-the-viewports-camera-view/23409#23409

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Flip/Invert* the Resolution X & Y properties in the Dimensions Panel *(Properties > Output > Resolution)*.

[image]