# Weird blueprint render result

Tags: rendering

I receive a very distorted output result when trying to render my finished blueprints. I follow a tutorial in which the instructor converts lines made of hundreds of vertices into a curve, chooses Full as Fill Type and applies some bevel to it. He then makes a material with black as diffuse color & viewport color. Before rendering, he ticks the Transparent box in Film category in Render menu and chooses RGBA and PNG. I did the same but my render is very weird. How can I fix it?

[image: Viewport]
[image: Weird render result]

My blend file: [CGIVI_test](https://filebin.net/xq5d8w0r0tiyiwpq)
Note: Layer 10 and 11 are original lines; layer 1 and 2 are curves.
The tutorial in case you need: https://bit.ly/2MudMeR (11:35 mark)

Comment: Have you changed your aspect ratio settings. See here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23408/rendered-aspect-ratio-different-from-the-viewports-camera-view

Comment: Yes I did change my aspect ratio setting. Thank you for your comment, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've changed the camera aspect ratio on Y. Use 1 on X and Y and then change the resolution X and Y to make it look like what you want.
[image: camera aspect]

Comment: You've solved my problem. Thank you! Too bad I cant debug this simple error myself.