# The camera is scaled like this and the render image is also stretched'

Tags: camera

This is what it looks like in the veiwport

[image]

Comment: Hello :). What exactly is your question? To scale the camera viewport size, go to *Camera Tab > Viewport*.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I want to know how to make it have the default dimensions, and how this might have happened, The image is stretched in the render as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "for some reason" the only reason is because you changed settings, without knowing what they are for.

Do you know what the aspect X and aspect Y controls do?
If you don't, then don't touch them. Set them back to 1.

Also, moving the scale for the camera in the 3d vieport will only affect how big it looks on the viewport, but will have no effect on the render whatsoever.

I suspect you wanted to change the field of view of the camera, as in the zoom lens of a camera, if so, then change (and animate) the lens size (focal length).

[image]

To understand what the aspect controls are for read:

[Rendered aspect ratio different from the viewport's camera view](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23408/rendered-aspect-ratio-different-from-the-viewports-camera-view/23409#23409)

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix for the size part without changing the aspect is to decrease the viewport size of the camera.[image]